# JSDoc reference object variable in @type

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Let's say I have the following JS:

```js
let myObj = {
    foo: function(a, b) {},
    bar: function(a) {}
};
```

Can I reference `myObj` as a type in JSDoc:

```js
/*
 * @param {myObj} param
 */
function (param) {}
```

Reading the [JSDoc @type](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html) documentation, it says a symbol name can be used, but I'm not sure exactly what counts as a "symbol". All the examples I've seen and other questions on stackoverflow show a class name being used, but I'm not defining a class in this case.

For a little more context, I have been defining objects such as this above example using a `@typedef` and manually listing all the properties. However, this is tedious and feels like code duplication. I recently discovered that PhpStorm still recognizes the return type and has code hints without the `@typedef` tags, but I'm unsure if this is part of JSDoc or just PhpStorm is smart enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `@namespace` in front of your `myObj` like following example.
Then, you could use obj name as type to pass it to other type definition.
Note: this is vscode.

[image]

[image]

But, the **obj name must be the same**.
Otherwise, it'll not work.

[image]